# Vectorization a code to make it faster than this

Tags: python, vectorization

I have a little bit code which I'll have to vectorizate it to make it faster. I'm not very attached into python and thinking that the for loop is not so efficient.

Is there any way to reduce the time?

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()

N = 10000000 #9 seconds
#N = 100000000 #93 seconds

alpha = np.linspace(0.00000000000001, np.pi/2, N)

tmp = 2.47*np.sin(alpha)
for i in range(N):
    if (abs(tmp[i])>1.0):
        tmp[i]=1.0*np.sign(tmp[i])
beta = np.arcsin(tmp)

end = time.time()
print("Executed time: ",round(end-start,1),"Seconds")
```

I read about some numpy functions but I don't have a solution for this.

Comment: Which numpy functions have you tried and what's the challenge

Comment: tmp = (tmp>1.0).any() where I can check if there is a number greater than 1.0 (but I think this is not a numpy function). I don't know how I can change the numbers, which are greater than 1.0, to 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clip the array:

```
tmp = np.clip(2.47 * np.sin(alpha), -1.0, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using loop with condition, you can access the values by computing a mask. Here is example:

```py
N = 10000000

alpha = np.linspace(0.00000000000001, np.pi/2, N)

tmp = 2.47*np.sin(alpha)
indices = np.abs(tmp) > 1.0
tmp[indices] = np.sign(tmp[indices])
beta = np.arcsin(tmp)
```

Results on my setup:

- before: `5.66 s ± 30.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`,
- after: `182 ms ± 877 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`.

Comment: What about clipping?

Comment: @MadPhysicist checked and it gave me `150 ms ± 451 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`, so your solution is better.